# Stuck with integrating d3 with data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>D3 Demo: SVG with data</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var dataset = {
    "entry":[
    {"date": "2011-03-18T00:00:04"},
    {"date": "2011-04-18T00:05:03"},
    {"date": "2011-03-29T00:10:04"},
    {"date": "2011-05-19T00:15:03"},
    {"date":"2011-06-12T00:20:03"},
    {"date": "2011-08-09T00:25:03"}
    ],

 "entry" :[
    {"date": "2012-03-18T00:00:04"},
    {"date": "2012-04-18T00:05:03"},
    {"date": "2012-03-29T00:10:04"},
    {"date": "2012-05-19T00:15:03"},
    {"date":"2012-06-12T00:20:03"},
    {"date": "2012-08-09T00:25:03"}
    ]
}

console.log(dataset.entry);

var height = 600;
var width = 500;
var x = d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(2011, 0, 1,23,33,00), new Date(2013, 0, 1, 23, 59)]).range([0, width]);



var svg = d3.selectAll("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width",width)
.attr("height",height)
.attr("shape-rendering","crispEdges");


svg.selectAll("body")
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("width", 4)
.attr("height",12)
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(new Date(d.entry.date)); } )
.attr("y",function(d,i){return i*10;})
.attr("fill","steelblue");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a simple file which I have created . The intention is to mimic the gantt chart. As you can see there are total 12 values which are there in the arrays . I am doing something wrong which is causing nothing to be printed.

Can anyone guide me ?

Comment: Check you website in Chrome and see what error is it giving you in the Console.

Comment: `dataset` is an object. No JSON in sight. Afaik, `.data` expects to be passed an array, not an object.

Comment: It is valid JSON @FelixKling

Comment: @Siddharth: No it is not. The code posted is JavaScript, not JSON. JSON is a data format just like XML. If you copy everything from the first `{` to the last `}` and put it in its own file or in a string, then yes, you have JSON. This is an important difference to understand.

Comment: Okay. Can't it be called a JSON Object here? @FelixKling

Comment: @Siddharth: No, that's just misleading. I recommend to read ["There's no such thing as a "JSON Object""](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 1):

The data, passed to the d3 selection, should be an array. I think what you want is this:

```
svg.selectAll("body")
  .data(dataset.entry)
  ...
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(new Date(d.date)); } )
```

Also, delete one of your "entry" attributes of "dataset". They appear to be duplicated in your current code, which I suspect to be a copy/paste error.

If it is not a copy/paste error, you can't define two "entry" elements, named identically - you would need to convert dataset to an array. IE:

```
var dataset = [ [ {"date": "blah" } ], [ {"date":"blah" } ] ];
```

And change the manner in which you access the data.

Comment: thanks a lot cmonkey it helped . By the way can you please suggest me a proper link where I can learn about Json?